# WebStorm - React-Native App simulator not working

Tags: ios, react-native, webstorm

I created a brand new React-Native app using WebStorm. When I click on Run -> iOS to fire in iOS simulator, I don't see iOS simulator loading. I don't see any errors also. Here is the screenshot after I run the project.
[image]
[image]

Now I could run `react-native run-ios` to get iOS simulator to work (btw which works), but I would like WebStorm to fire simulator so that I can use in-built debugger in WebStorm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What webStorm and react-native versions do you use? looks similar to [WEB-29569](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-29569), fixed in 2017.3

Comment: Note that I'd strongly recommend using `Chrome` debugger process rather than `Node` when debugging React Native with Node.js 8+

Comment: Thanks!! Upgrading to 2017.3 worked for me. I spend 2 hours trying to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that WebStorm uses not latest version of `react native` that caused some troubles with Xcode version.

First **you need to upgrade your Xcode** to currently latest version.

Second you would better **use stable version of Node JS**.

I recommend you not to create app with WebStorm. For today the best way to create new app is `create-react-native-app` command line tool. It will create app using expo kit. As app will be initialized - run `npm start` (or better `yarn start` if you have it, because `yarn` is optimized version of `npm`). As it loaded it will show you QR code in terminal witch is you should read with your device and it will install Expo App and open your app inside it. Also you can press `i` to run iOS simulator.

Here is short documentation for creating app with `create-react-native-app`. Follow this steps and everything will be all right.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html